# Writing a buffer (void*) to rocksdb

Tags: c++, rocksdb

I want to write a buffer (`const void* buffer`) into rocksdb.

I did:

```
rocksdb::DB* db;
rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options,"~/testdb", &db);

var = 0;
std::string key("k" + std::to_string(var));
db->Put(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), key, buffer);
```

and I have the problem that:

`No matching member function for call to 'Put'`

If I replaced `buffer` by dummy value, such as `"abc"`, there is no problem. Therefore, I think the problem is `buffer` variable.

So, given a general pointer and its length, how could I write the buffer to rocksdb?

Comment: What exactly is `buffer` - what type?

Comment: @Ajay `const void*`

Comment: @GillBates, Alright, I am not aware of this rocksdb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast your pointer to `const char*`:

```
db->Put(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), key, (const char*)buffer);
```

Make sure that `buffer` is a valid `C` string though.

Comment: Hello, in case ``buffer`` is a binary data, what should I do? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: u need to take a look at rocksdb's API, it use Slice to wrap key/value arguments.